# How to select non contiguous lines of code in Notepad++?

Tags: notepad++, text-editing

What key enables the selection of non-consecutive lines in Notepad++?

I have some Matlab code I have edited with Notepad++. I would like to select distinct (non consecutive) blocks of code in order to perform Find&Replace within my selected code only.

This wouldn't be a problem if this was to be done in one continuous block of code, but how can I select little blocks from all over the script? In Word or Excel, the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> key would do the trick; what's its Notepad++ equivalent?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

from the help:

> If a stream area is selected, it is possible to add another, disjoint
> area by Ctrl-clicking its start point and moving the mouse to the end
> point. More than one extra selection can be added this way.
> (Multi-Editing should be enabled in Preferences)

Source: http://npp-community.tuxfamily.org/documentation/selecting-text

**tl;dr** - `Settings` -> `Preferences` -> `Editing` -> `Enable Multi-Editing` -> check. Then <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-Click for each section.

[image: Enable Multi-Editing setting screenshot]

Comment: Thank you very much! This is going to save me a lot of time.

Comment: Tip: use **character selection** not line selection. The Multi-Editing feature does not empower you to select multiple _lines_ of code. Though you can select all the _characters_ in multiple lines. So when you use the Ctrl-Click be sure it's inside the text, and not on the line numbers.

Answer (score 2):

For some reason, Ctrl-clicking in the line numbers selects ALL lines (even when Multi-Editing is enabled), not the non-consecutive lines needed.

Bookmarks provide a way to cut/copy/paste these lines, but if a large section of consecutive lines needs bookmarking, a bookmark is only added to one line (where the cursor is, even though the user had selected all these lines before choosing "Toggle Bookmark").

An easy way around this is Search menu >> Mark... >> Mark tab, checking the boxes "Bookmark line" & "In selection", entering . in the "Find what" box, and selecting "Regular expression" in the Search Mode section.  Then click "Mark All" and all lines in the selection which contain at least one character should be bookmarked.

Hope this helps

Comment: Yes, Ctrl-clicking the line numbers selects all lines. Weird. But **Ctrl-character-swiping** will select multiple swaths of characters (when Multi-Editing is enabled).